# How can we feed our custom synonym word list to NLP model (Word2Vec is preferred)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, nltk

I am using Word2Vec  model for making a vectorizer from my data.
My data has custom/business defined synonym word list which i want my NLP model should consider.
For e.g if "A" is a synonym of "B" then if i try to find synonym word for "A" using Word2Vec then it should give "B" with 100% match.

I can try different NLP models as well provided i am able to achieve the above requirement.

Comment: I'm confused - what stops you from just replacing all synonyms before vectorization or manually assigning synonyms the same word vector after training?

Comment: @CecilCox thanks for replying. Manually doing it is a possibility but the data is huge, I am looking for a solution where NLP model can take custom synonym list as an input. Any idea about not doing it manually ?

Comment: Can I get some idea of the scale? How large are your data and synonym lists?

Comment: Total Documents - 2 million, Each doc has average 800 words so total 1.6 billion words. Synonym words list is around 21k words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your synonym list is very small, I'd recommend you train your model, then loop through your synonym list, reassigning the word vector of each synonym in your model (and adding any that were not present in your training data). This of course destroys any information about the learned word vectors, which depending on your use case may be a problem.

Some alternative approaches:

1. Reassign word vectors to a composite of their constituent synonyms (e.g. mean). Unfortunately this works best if your synonyms already had similar vectors, which I assume is not the case. In general this probably loses more semantic information than it preserves.
2. Add synonyms as duplicate words, (ie,a given word will have two vectors, one inferred from the training data and one equal to it's synonym). This preserves semantic relationships but creates ambiguity whenever you need to perform a computation using a vector that could have a synonym. How big of an issue this is depends on your use case.
3. Apply a projection to your word embeddings subject to certain constraints (synonym equality). I've never tried this so I'm unsure how it impacts your model, how difficult it would be to compute, or what objective function you'd need to optimize.
4. Preprocess your text. Yes, it'll take a while, but compute is cheap these days.

Comment: Going to advocate for #4 here.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. This question was posted for a use case where I am matching documents and then generating a matching score. In my case TF-IDF combined with Sigmoid kernel was giving a better score than Word2Vec combined with Cosine Similarity. Can you please throw some light how can i take care of synonyms with TF-IDF + Sigmoid kernel. Option 4 seems a possibility but anything better and faster than that. @CecilCox

Comment: If you're using tf-idf then just preprocess your text. Any other approach will just be an attempt to approximate your list, and will do so very poorly.